# Change multiple fields with useState()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I have this situation: one table with fields "available" and "borrower" present. The user once clicks on the "borrow" button, the state is updated with "borrowerId" added to it and "available" switched from true to false.

What can I do is obviously update the state with two buttons but I can't find a way to update more than one field in the object in useState. Here is my code:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(book);

const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    
    const value = auth.decodedUser.userId;
    if (state) {
      setState({
        ...state,
        
        [name]: value,
      });
    }
  };



<Button
         name="borrowerId"
         type="submit"
         variant="outlined"
         color="inherit"
         onClick={handleChange}
         >
         borrow
 </Button>
```

What I wanna do is something like this:

```
const handleChange = (e: any) => {
        const userId = auth.decodedUser.userId;
        if (state) {
          setState({
            ...state,
            available: false,
            borrowerId: userId,
          });
        }
      };
```

But I've tried and no success. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following example

I've replaced thinks like `book` and `auth.decodedUser.userId` with some dummy values

Showing the current state hook by rendering `{JSON.stringify(value)}`

Press the button to see the changes made by `handleChange()`

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState({ 
        name: 'some book', 
        available: true, 
        borrowerId: null
    });
    
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const userId = 16;
        setValue({
            ...value,
            available: false,
            borrowerId: userId,
        });
    };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div
               name="borrowerId"
               variant="outlined"
               color="inherit"
               onClick={handleChange}
               >Borrow
           </div>
           <hr />
           {JSON.stringify(value)}
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```